# bash-as-sh echo -n

Tags: bash, echo

Is there a way to get bash (version 3.2.57(1), if it matters),
in the mode where it's emulating sh, to implement the `-n` option
to the `echo` builtin?

Specifically, I'm curious whether there might be one option I could set somewhere, rather than seeking out and rewriting N calls to `echo -n` in M different scripts, that had — perhaps only by dumb luck — been working fine for years.
Clearly it's possible for bash's `echo`
builtin to implement `-n`, because in full bash mode, it does.

[Disclaimer: Yes, I know that `echo -n` is not portable in the first place, and that `printf` is recommended.]

---

Side note: Commentators have noted that this version of bash is "17 years old".  Someone should tell Apple about this — it's the version that came with MacOS Ventura 13.0 on the reasonably new Mac where I'm typing this.

Comment: Use `printf` instead.

Comment: @choroba Question updated.

Comment: interestingly, typing `echo -n foo` into `sh --posix` (bash 5.2) works beautifully. So, yes, might really depend on version (and yours is 17 years old, so things might have reasonably changed!)

Comment: I think this is an XY problem. There might be a bunch of ways to do this (use some other `echo` like in @MarcusMüller's answer, or just turn off POSIX emulation with `set +o posix` and then run `echo` (or make `echo` a wrapper function that does this and then does `set -o posix` again). But we can't say if any of that is going to be useful for you.

Comment: You can use this in sh: `bash -c 'echo -n "Line 1\nAlso Line 1\n"'` or you just use `/bin/echo`.

Comment: @paladin Using `/bin/echo` is a decent workaround which I was already considering.  I was hoping for an option — and you've given me one!  `set +o posix` is quite likely exactly what I want.  Make that an answer, and I'll accept it!

Comment: @Muru Oh, there's definitely an XY problem lurking here, except that I really am wondering if there's an answer to Y.  The answer to "How do I portably echo something without a newline?" is well known.  But here I'm really asking, "bash implements `echo -n` in bash mode.  For some reason it makes a *different* choice in sh mode.  Is there a way to tell it to make the same choice, to implement `-n` in sh mode also?  And Stéphane Chazelas has now answered most of that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I'm thinking it's likely a compile-time option rather than the version. The Bash 3.2 I had compiled with the default options did respect `-n` even in POSIX mode. There's at least `./configure --enable-xpg-echo-default`, but that actually sets `xpg_echo`, while it's not shown as set in the Mac one. So it might just be that the Mac `sh` just has some other difference.

Comment: My own Mac tells me over-and-over that zsh is the new default shell, not bash... I've not switched over... but you might check out the behavior of echo in zsh...

Comment: @paulgarrett, the default interactive shell is zsh. But `/bin/sh` is still a version of Bash.

Answer (score 3):

The best idea I could come up with is replacing the builtin `echo` with the "real" `echo` executable from the GNU coreutils, that is almost certainly installed if you have a bash:

```bash
echo() { "$(type -P echo)" "$@" ; }
```

which simply shadows the built-in.

Since GNU Coreutil's `echo.c` really isn't very long, and a good part of that is special-case handling for things like "am I running on UNIX System V and am expected to behave like that?", `--help` printing and similar things you don't *strictly* need, you might consider just including a small C implementation of `echo` in your shell scripts and put it through the POSIX-specified `c99` if you know that you got that. Heck, this is a machine from the 2000s, so you might as well assume you have perl and implement the same in perl.

Comment: "this is a machine from the 2000s" Or it might be macOS

Comment: @muru Indeed. 

Comment: heh, interesting!

Comment: Or create a shell script to implement `echo` :) Somehow, running `type` in a subshell on every invocation of that function feels bad to me. I'd be tempted to do something like `eval "echo() { '$(type -P echo)' \"\$@\" ; }"` instead (taking the risk of single quotes in the path). Or just store the path in a variable. It's not likely it's likely to change anyway...

Answer (score 3):

As seen at [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803), `bash` doesn't support the `-n` option (nor `-e`/`-E`) when both the `posix` option is enabled (like when invoked as `sh`) and the `xpg_echo` option is enabled (as it is by default on systems where bash is built so as to be UNIX compliant).

So to have bash's `echo` support `-n` (and `-e`/`-E` and combinations thereof like `echo -en`, `echo -e -n`...), you need to disable either or both of those options. If you want that `sh` to still be UNIX-compliant except for that `-n`, it's probably `xpg_echo` only that you want to turn off:

```
shopt -u xpg_echo
```

Example:

```
$ bash -o posix -O xpg_echo -c 'echo -n a'
-n a
$ bash -o posix -O xpg_echo -c 'shopt -u xpg_echo; echo -n a'
a
```

bash is still mostly UNIX-compliant, except for the `-n` that was not printed.

```
$ bash -o posix -O xpg_echo -c 'set +o posix; echo -n a'
a
```

That `-n` handling is enabled, but also some other non-UNIX compliances so it behaves even less like standard `sh`.

Comment: Yowza.  I was hoping for an option like `xpg_echo` — that looks like precisely what I want.  Thank you very much.  Unfortunately, although it exists in this version of bash, it doesn't seem to behave as described.  I'll play with it some more tonight.  Thanks again.

Comment: On my Mac, it shows `xpg_echo` is _off_ for `sh`. I suppose the behaviour might be set by some hard compile-time setting?

Comment: @ilkkachu, it works for me as I describe with a bash 3.2.57 built with `configure --enable-xpg-echo-default --enable-strict-posix-default`. Presumably Apple has broken it further so it behave like the xpg_echo way even when xpg_echo is off. In any case, that would be a bug as it would not work as documented (where `xpg_echo` off means `-e`/`-E`/`-n` are handled).

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function with the necessary functionality

```
echo() ( IFS=' ' nl='\n'; [ "$1" = '-n' ] && shift && nl=; printf "%s$nl" "$*" )
```

In `dash` (admittedly not `bash` in `sh` mode, and definitely not the version you have), this avoids external references.

Note that [POSIX says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) the only guaranteed compatible way to use `echo` is without arguments or backslash escapes:

> If the first operand is `-n`, or if any of the operands contain a *<backslash>* character, the results are implementation-defined.

If you want the extended version that handles backslash escapes, use `%b` instead of `%s`:

```
echo() ( IFS=' ' nl='\n'; [ "$1" = '-n' ] && shift && nl=; printf "%b$nl" "$*" )
```

Comment: true! that works and is probably faster; I don't know posix enough to know whether we  have to care about things like `echo -e -n '\t\tfoo'`

Comment: `"$*"` joins the positional parameters with the first character of `$IFS`, so you'd also need a `local IFS=' '`. Also, standard `echo` is meant to escape `\x` sequences, so `%b` may be preferable (maybe not if the OP expects `echo` to work in a non-standard fashion).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas given that the only POSIX guaranteed `echo` is one that does not handle either `-n` or escaped characters I'm not overly worried. The `IFS` issue is a fair point though and I'll address that now

Comment: @ChrisDavies, UNIX (POSIX with XSI option) guarantees that no option are supported and that escape sequences **are** expanded. Without XSI, you get no guarantee at all.

Answer (score 1):

The external `/bin/echo` on my Mac does support `-n`, and you can disable the Bash builtin one with `enable -n`:

```
bash-3.2$ enable -n echo
bash-3.2$ type echo
echo is /bin/echo
bash-3.2$ echo -n foo |od -c
0000000    f   o   o
0000003
```

Answer (score 1):

### Fix the Underlying Issue

Google will return a plethora of results if you use "Upgrade bash macOS" as the search term.  Using a native exchange answer, and combining 2 answers into one (Per your Side note):

[Frequently Asked Questions about the GNU Licenses: Tivoization](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#Tivoization)

> When people distribute User Products that include software under GPLv3, section 6 requires that they provide you with information necessary to modify that software. User Products is a term specially defined in the license; examples of User Products include portable music players, digital video recorders, and home security systems.

Since Apple's Darwin OS has been closed source since about 10.5, providing an upgraded BASH would violate the above paragraph, so Apple does know.  There is a way to update the BASH shell and even make it the default:

### Install Updated Bash Via Homebrew

Paste the following in your terminal:

1. `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"` as one line.
2. Issue `brew install bash`

This should install an updated version of BASH in Homebrew which is then symlinked. Use `which bash` to find the location To set this as the default:

1. Edit `/etc/shells`.
2. Add the path + the binary to the file at the end.
3. Logout and back in to update your environment.
4. Use the `chsh` command to "Change Shells", providing the path to the new BASH version. This should make the new version your default shell.

### Sources

- [AskDifferent: Update bash to version 4.0 on OSX](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193411/update-bash-to-version-4-0-on-osx)
- [Homebrew: The Missing Package Manager for MacOS](https://brew.sh/)

Comment: The question here though is about the `echo` builtin of `/bin/sh` on macos which is a build of an ancient version of bash (for the reason you mention) configured with --enable-strict-posix-default --enable-xpg-echo-default

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I totally agree that the question is RE: echo, and I put this answer here as an option to the OP if he chooses to do so. Personally I would but it's not up to me. Using this answer would possibly alleviate the need for a fix in the first place, but if I've learned anything from contributing here, it's that there are about a million different solutions to every problem.

Answer (score -2):

On the macOS 14.3 version of bash, unsetting `posix` seems to be enough:

```
% /bin/sh -c 'set +o posix; echo -n foo; set -o posix; echo -n bar'
foo-n bar
% /bin/sh --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin23)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: Curious, `sh +o posix -c ...` didn't work.

Comment: Probably Bash sets `posix` based on argv[0] after parsing the options